# Using an alternate password for Windows 10 account linked to live

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords

It seems that I am forced to use my Live account password to login to my Windows 10 laptop. This is problematic because my password is complex, since I only usually ever need to type it once. I have slightly easier to remember passwords for things I have to type all the time.

Is there any way to change the password without changing my live password? Or how do I disconnect my live account from my user on Windows and use a standard local login?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use another authentication method to [login](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-login-pin-code-or-picture-password-windows-10)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Or how do I disconnect my live account from my user on Windows and use
>   a standard local login?

You can disconnect a local profile connected to a Microsoft Account through the following actions.

1. Launch the **Settings** application.
2. Click on **Accounts**

[image]

3. Click **Sign in with a local account instead**.

[image]

4. Follow on screen prompts and specify a local username to be created.

[image]
[image]
[image]

5. Done

> Is there any way to change the password without changing my live
>   password?

Alternatively, you can use Windows Hello, Pin, or Picture password

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason this answer received a downvote?  What can I do to improve the answer?  The answer addresses all the author's questions in specific and glorious detail.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any way to change the password without changing my live password?

Set up a PIN under "Sign-in options". Recent Windows versions no longer require the PIN to be numerical, so it can fully act as a local password.